# Grafana - Combine Results after some Regex operations

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, grafana, dashboard

We have a table in Grafana with an elastic search data source. I try to combine all the results by the part of the string which I call "Name".

Here are the results of our query:

**Results**

| Message | Count |
| --- | --- |
| ResourceInvalidOperation-John | 5 |
| ResourceInvalidOperation-Mary | 10 |
| ResourceContent-George | 7 |
| BusinessInvalidContent-John | 6 |
| ResourceInvalidOperation-George | 9 |
| ResourceReference-John | 1 |

Pattern in the results is "XXXXX-**Name**" I need to get the **Name **part so I used "Value Mappings" with the regex   **(.*)(-)(.*)$** --> and get **$3**

However this gave me result as

| Name | Count |
| --- | --- |
| John | 5 |
| Mary | 10 |
| George | 7 |
| John | 6 |
| George | 9 |
| John | 1 |

Can you help me to make the result as below ?

| Name | Count |
| --- | --- |
| John | 12 |
| Mary | 10 |
| George | 16 |

I tried "Transform" --> "Filter by name" and "Rename by Regex". However couldn't figure it out.

I'd be glad if someone can guide me?

Comment: Do you mean you want to remove duplicate results?

Comment: Not just to remove , I want to get the unique names with a sum of count numbers. I realised that I missed a part so just edited my question to make it more clear.

Comment: *Value Mappings* in Grafana are just for displaying purposes. You can not aggregate based on them. You need either to use some transformation to change actual values (I can't any suitable for this case though), or transform data at the level of query to datasource. Then you'll have a chance to use transformation *Group by* in Grafana to get the exactly expected output.

Comment: Thank you @markalex , I understood that "Value Mappings" is useless for this case after I did, There are 2 Transform options
"Rename by regex" - Renames part of the query result by using regular experssion with placeholders
"Filter by name" - Removes part of the query result using a regex pattern. The pattern can be inclusive or exclusive 
would these options work somehow? ( I tried but couldn't change anything )

Comment: Mentioned transformations do not transform data, but query name and column correspondingly. You could try transpose, rename, transpose, but I'm not sure if this is even possible. I'd suggest investigating if it's possible to get your data from data source already cleared.

Comment: Thanks for the commenct @markalex , I'll try some more stuff but unfortunately to get the data already clean and ready is not an option.